# A notation about conditional expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation

Suppose $dX_t=b\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t$ and $X_0=x$

$g$ is a measurable function.

What does $\mathbb{E}[g(X_T^{t,Y})]$ mean? Is it a number or R.V.?

It confuses me  because I think there are two explanations:

(1) $\mathbb{E}[g(X_T^{t,Y})]=\mathbb{E}[g(X_T)|X_t=Y]=\mathbb{E}^{t,x}[g(X_T)]|_{x=Y}$

(2) Solve $dX_t=b\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t$ and $X_t=Y$, then take the expectation of $X_T$

The result in (1)  is a R.V. but in (2)  is a number. which one is correct? 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $Y$ a random variable?

Comment: @Gordon yes $Y$ is a random variable.

Comment: The most plausible interpretation is (2). To mean (1), the authors would probably write $$E(g(X_T^{t,Y})\mid Y)$$